# How to prevent MongoClient to stop executing code on duplicate key error

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to add records to a mongodb collection, using the mongo client for node, this is my code

```
const participants = db.collection('participants');
await participants.createIndex({ email: 1, survey: 1 }, { unique: true });

await participants.insertMany(participantToSave, {ordered: false}, (err, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("error saving new participants");
  }
  console.log("Number of documents inserted: " + res.insertedCount);
});
```

if there is any duplicate in my **participantToSave** array, the option **{ unique: true }** prevents from stop inserting, so all the records are correctly saved.

My problem is that a **MongoBulkWriteError: E11000 duplicate key error** error is throwed anyway, so all the code after this block is not executed.

I am looking for a way to avoid this. I already tried with a try/catch block with no luck.

```
try {
  insertedParticipants = await participants.insertMany(participantToSave, {ordered: false});
} catch (e) {
  console.log("e");
  console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: please show the `participantToSave`, or try to put key `_id: ObjectId()` within the objetc of  `participantToSave`

Comment: Would you show your `try`/`catch` attempt?

Comment: The `catch` block is never executed?

Comment: Try explicit bulk insert https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/node/current/usage-examples/bulkWrite/#example